# Where to perform generic resource cleanup for all jersey apis

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

A bunch of jersey rest apis have been written in our product and we are experiencing some database resource exhausting issues. We know what resource clean up to perform, but could not figure out a generic class or method to create so that it gets automatically called at the end of every GET/PUT/POST/DELETE rest api call. 
I went through the jersey documentation, although it talks about resource management, it does not mention any specific class which gets called after every api call.  Should we use Filters or Interceptors or is there something very basic that I am missing here.

Comment: If you are using per-request resource classes (not singletons), Jersey supports the `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` annotations for arbitrary methods. Or you can look into the [`CloseableService`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.13/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/CloseableService.html). Hard to say any more without some more details

Comment: Thanks  peeskillet, yes, I am using per-request resource classes, but using @PreDestroy I would have to write multiple implementations for different resources.

Comment: Are you using any DI for the db services?

Comment: Yes, I am, I got the solution, would post it as answer here on stackoverflow in some time.